# Regex look ahead to seperate string into tokens

Tags: java, regex

I currently have the following code which allows me to find matches from a String.

I need to be able to find all words similar to `64x`and split them up into tokens, so I'll get `64` and `x` as the output.

I have looked at regexs lookahead and this does not solve the issue, is there a way to do this without creating a new arraylist to store matches similar to `64x` then splitting them up?

```
        String input = "Hello world 65x";

        ArrayList<String> userInput = new ArrayList<>();

        Matcher isMatch = Pattern.compile("[0-9]*+[a-zA-Z]")
                .matcher(input);
        while (isMatch.find()) {
            userInput.add(isMatch.group());
        }
```

Comment: What is so specific about `65x`? See https://ideone.com/ROcBxX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following regular expression:

```
\b(\p{Digit}+)(\p{Alpha})\b
```

Additionally, if you plan to use the regular expression very often, it is recommended to use a constant in order to avoid recompile it each time, e.g.:

```java
private static final Pattern REGEX_PATTERN = 
        Pattern.compile("\\b(\\p{Digit}+)(\\p{Alpha})\\b");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "Hello world 65x";
    Matcher matcher = REGEX_PATTERN.matcher(input);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
65
x
```

Answer (score 1):

No need of lookaheads, you can use nested captured groups:

```
Matcher isMatch = Pattern.compile("\\b([0-9]+)([a-zA-Z])\\b");
```

Group #1 will contain `65` and group #2 will contain `x`.

Better to add `\\b` (word boundary) on either side to avoid matching `abc56xyz`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use [`Matcher.group(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group(int)). This lets you extract pieces of the matched text. Read about caputring groups [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#cg). A regex that contains capturing groups is `\\b([0-9]+)([a-zA-Z])\\b` (as given by anubhava).